# Returning from a function in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

I have to update a Excel file, which contains a Visual Basic routine attached to a button.
I tried to prevent the routine from run with empty data and wanted to do an early return:

```
Sub FillProductDetail()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    set wks = Worksheets("Product Detail")

    Dim ProductToShow As String
    ProductToShow = wks.Range("C4")
    wks.Rows("5:1000")Delete Shift :=xlUp

    If ProductToShow = "" Then
        Return
    End If

    ..... many lines which take forever if ProductToShow is empty

End Sub
```

I know how to include the rest of the function in the If statement, that works, but then everything is indented even further to the right. I have seen the Return statement before in Basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Exit Sub`
in a subroutine

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillProductDetail()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim ProductToShow As String
    ProductToShow = wks.Range("C4")
    wks.Rows("5:1000").Delete Shift:=xlUp

    If ProductToShow = "" Then GoSub MyRoutine
    Exit Sub

MyRoutine:
    MsgBox "Empty cell"
    Return
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually I use 'If ... Then Exit Sub Endif' now, without the extra GoSub.

Comment: you could consider using a routing since you've said there are tons of lines of code to execute if the cell is empty.

Comment: i have been unclear, if the rest of the function would run with empty value it takes long, the value should always be set. I would upvote your answer as it works, but I am not allowed yet.

Comment: Thats ok. Im glad youve cleared what was needed and got your answer!